# No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory' has been registered

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nuget-package

Visual Studio 2019. c#.
Existing unit test after some changes started to be failed with error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory' has been registered.

Interesting thing is that no direct changes were introduced to the tested code.
A few packages updated and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to resolve the issue it needs to
Install package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7 (version for the time of the publishing the post)

and after that I had to implement IHttpClientFactory

Because of it is test it was simple

```
    public class HttpClientFactoryTest : IHttpClientFactory
    {
        public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            var inMemoryServer = new HttpServer(config);
            return new HttpClient(inMemoryServer);
        }
    }
```

Then it also needed to register type like that

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IHttpClientFactory, HttpClientFactoryTest>();
```

After that the error disappeared.

That's it

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).